# Removing the focus of the Editbox in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

all

When i clicked in the EditText box to type something the border color of the EditTet box was changed.I dont need that,but i want to enter the text in the EditText box.

I tried a xml tag tag

```
android:focusable="false".
```

But its not working .How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this probably will work..

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
protected void onFocuschanged(){

editText.setBackground(@android:drawable.editbox_background);
}
});
```

go to editText in xml and add this tag,

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Comment: the entire EditText box color was changed and i need to enter the text in the edittext box

Comment: its working thank you but i have one more doubt i gave edittext width=200 and height=300 when i select editbox it shows cursor at middle .how to move the cursor to top-left.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of is just use the editbox_background_normal ninepatch image and make yourself a selector that uses this image for the background in all states (default, focused, pressed) that way the view will not appear to the user to change at all.

Then just set the background of the EditText to your selector.

[image: Here is the default hdpi image for EditTexts from SDK-8]